# Хранение данных расширения Chrome у себя на сервере

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension, cors

Через расширение для Chome хочу отправлять на сервер и получать обратно данные со страниц сайтов. Использую для этого jquery. При отправке с сайта(когда использую расширение на том же сайте) на котором обработчик php-ный находится- все отрабатывает нормально, но при отправке с других сайтов система отказывается работать сообщая следующее:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://site.ru/poe.php' from origin 'https://www.liveinternet.ru' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

CORS это штуковина которую можно уговорить(по данным из Гугла) пропускать запросы добавив что-то в Файл Манифеста. Вроде можно просто указать в  permissions скрипт обработчика и все должно быть хорошо, но нет...

Файл manifest.json :

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "poe",
"description": "123",
"version": "1.0.0",
"content_scripts":[
{
"matches": ["<all_urls>"],
"js": [ "jquery-1.5.1.min.js", "script.js"],
"run_at": "document_end"
}

],
"permissions": ["http://*/", "*://*/*", "https://site.ru/poe.php", "<all_urls>"],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://site.ru/poe.php; object-src 'self'"
}
```

В чем проблема?
Что нужно сделать чтобы запросы на свой сервер с любых страниц работали?

Comment: @InDevX  Я это читал, я попробую если не будет других ответов, конечно, но это для запросов сайт-сайт, а для расширений, вроде музыка своя:  прописываем каким сайтам доверяем в манифест и, при установке пользователю говорят что расширение вот этим доверяет, подтвердите что и вы тоже. (информация не проверенная) Растолкуйте пож. кто понимает хорошо.

Comment: Не внимательно смотрел.. `"permissions": ["http://*/", "http://*/*", "https://*/", "https://*/*"]` со 100% рабочего проекта

Comment: @InDevX Нельзя ли растолковать кто невнимательно смотрел? Я на статью по ссылке или ты(вы) на мой вопрос? Соответственно: Так дело в заголовке? Проверил этот вариант permissions- не работает... В любом случае благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Я ваш вопрос не внимательно смотрел. Это с манифеста трёхлетней давности, возможно уже что-то поменялось, тут уж ничем помочь не смогу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается что разрешения из manifest.json относительно CORS распространяются на файлы pop-up-а(окно появляющееся при нажатии на иконку расширения), и файлы всплывающих сообщений расширения. Но не распространяются на content_scripts(скрипты подгружаемые в тело страницы) И для того чтобы отправлять на сервер инфу и получать обратно нужно пересылать ее через эти файлы, например с помощью API Хрома(еще, вероятно, возможно через chrome.storage ,  ...)- например вот так:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "GoodName"});  //создание соединения с файлом pop-up
port.postMessage({ack: dobav});  //пошла инфа {переменная: значение}
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {    //функция которая ждет ответ
console.log(msg.color);  //инфа из pop-up
});
```

В pop-up:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {

$.ajax({  //Аякс в городе
url: "site/obrabotchic.php", // куда отправляем
type: "post", // метод передачи
dataType: "json", // тип передачи данных
data: { // что отправляем
"info": msg.ack   
},
success: function(data){  //Аяксу пришел ответ с сервера
vasia = data.info;
port.postMessage({color: vasia});   //отправляем инфу в контент скрипт- в скобках 
название переменной и сама инфа
}})
});
});
```

В manifest.json добавляем [разрешения](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) на отправку запросов.