# Скрипт заблокирован политикой CORS

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

В расширении для Chrome я пытаюсь загрузить некоторый скрипт с помощью XMLHttpRequest, но получаю следующую ошибку:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' from origin '...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Как обойти политику CORS и всё таки загрузить нужный скрипт?

Comment: Грузи его через тег script

Comment: Каким конкретно образом?

Comment: Видимо, имеется в виду "впишите его url в тег <script>"

Comment: Это я понял. Добавить в head страницы ссылку на скрипт?

Comment: Проблема в том, что ответ сервера не может быть доступен коду, который отправляет запрос от имени моего origin. Есть ли способ для расширения отправить запрос так, чтобы браузер не указывал HTTP-заголовок origin?

Comment: @D.Stark Непрозрачная часть этого вопроса заключается вероятно в том что CORS content_scripts(скрипты подгружаемые в тело страницы) такой же как у самой страницы, ну или просто из-за "отдельного мира" content_script не может понюхать ответ сервера, а CORS popup и прочего задается в manifest.json . И если хотим что-то поместить в content_scripts со стороны, то тащим это через popup. Вот здесь вероятно похожая проблема с вашей решалась: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1192642/   Если не поможет, то напишите откуда и в какую часть chrome extension хотите подгрузить- подскажу.

Comment: Я решил проблему по другому: написал background script, в котором ко всем ответам сервера добавляется заголовок "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *".

Comment: @D.Stark Т.е. если сервер возвращает заголовок этот, то можно из content_scripts слать напрямую запросы с любого сайта себе на сервер? Думал(заблуждение) что сайт на котором работает content_scripts что-то еще должен отправлять при запросе кроме Origin: site  .  Не могли бы вы ответ оформить с серверной частью- на благо сообщества, а то трудно дойти до этого, особенно тем, кто впервые с CORS столкнулся.

Comment: Да, я собирался оформить ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение заключается в добавлении background script, который регистрирует обработчик события получения заголовков ответа сервера. В обработчике необходимо добавить в ответ сервера заголовок `access-control-allow-origin` со значением `*` - это заставляет браузер думать, что содержимое ответа сервера может быть доступно для любого "origin", который отправил запрос.

**background.js:**

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    function (details) {
        var rule = {
            "name": "access-control-allow-origin",
            "value": "*"
        };
        details.responseHeaders.push(rule);
        return { responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders };
    },
    { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
    ["blocking", "responseHeaders", "extraHeaders"]);
```

Так же добавим следующие строки в **manifest.json**:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
    "persistent": true
},
"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    ...
]
```